# iOS SDK Shopify: Change the sort order for the products in a collection

Tags: ios, shopify

You can select from a few sorting options:

Manually,
Best selling,
Product title A-Z,
Product title Z-A,
Highest price,
Lowest price,
Newest,
Oldest

Comment: You have to edit the collection.liquid file to place the sorting code on top of product list. I can help you in case if you need with this

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the collection.liquid file to place the sorting code on top of product list.
I can help you in case if you need with this